# How to check whether an array of items contains only this item?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
$items1 = ['apple', 'tree', 'juice'];
$items2 = ['apple', 'tree'];
$items3 = ['apple'];

// loop
If ($items[i].containsOnly['apple'])
{
  // do something..
}
```

In the simplified example above I want to get the array that matches the given item. Is there a method available similar to 'containsOnly'? Or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can check if the item is in the collection and the size of the collection too

Comment: Just to add you should rephrase your question because you say about `collection` but you give us arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple your logic with [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
function containsOnly($a, $v)
{
    return count($a) === 1 && array_values($a)[0] === $v; 
}
```

This will ensure that you have only one item and the value is equal to what you are searching for.

**Note:** The usage of [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) here is to reset all the indexes so we can ensure `[0]` is where the value will be. Instead of the `array_values` variation you can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if you prefer that.

Answer (score 5):

```
//If the array has the only item present    
   if(in_array('apple',$item) && count($item)==1)
    {
    //Do Something
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a collection of item groups, `->filter()` by the condition, then run code on `->each` item group which passed the condition.

```
$itemGroups[] = ['apple', 'tree', 'juice'];
$itemGroups[] = ['apple', 'tree'];
$itemGroups[] = ['apple'];

collect($itemGroups)
    ->filter(function($items, $key) {
        return count($items) == 1 && in_array('apple', $items);
    })
    ->each(function($items, $key) {
        // do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `contains`. From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-contains):

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]);

$collection->contains('Desk');

// true

$collection->contains('New York');

// false
```

I think the example is fairly simple. In your example it would look something like:

```
$collection = $items1->merge($items2)->merge($items3)
if($collection->contains('apple') && $collection->count() === 1){
  // it contains apple
}
```

Not tested tho but you get the idea behind it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to check if the item is the only one in the collection

Comment: @RomainB. You would like to check if that is the only one in the collection? Didn't get that. I will update the answer accordingly. EDITED: basically you just need to check if the number of items inside of the collection is `1` and if it contains `apple`

Comment: I don't, but it seems to be the question here ^^

Comment: Wouldn't `$collection->count()` equal `3` in this instance as it is not iterating over each array within the collection?

Comment: @thisiskelvin in this specific case yeah. I left a comment in OPs post because its not very clear what he means by `only apple` and he has 3 arrays containing other items

Comment: @Thedude I assumed that he meant of each of the arrays, there was only one value and the value was `apple`.

Comment: I think he wants the arrays with, and only with, the `apple`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $items=array_merge($items1,$items2,$items3);
    if (in_array("apple", $items)){
        echo "success";
    }
```

Comment: This answer will return true with array items1 and items2 only as well, right? It should only be true with array items3. (The items as arguments and items in the target array should match in number and value).